# How to set zsh as default for gnome terminal only?

Tags: gnome-terminal, zsh

I have configured my account to use zsh as default shell -with one of the helpful Oh-my-zsh themes. The theme requires some special fonts and rich colour scale. When I switch to terminal (e.g. by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>) or use some limited terminal emulator (e.g. embedded in IDE) it causes problems due to limited colourscale or fixed font.

How can I set the zsh with oh-my-zsh theme default only for gnome-terminal, so that the bash will remain the default one?

Comment: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-custom-command.html.en

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the instruction from @steeldriver 's comment (sorry, I can't upvote):

1. open the preferences (right click in the window or use the hamburger button)
2. go to configuration profile (I created a new one for ZSH by cloning the default)
3. select "Command" tab
4. tick "Run a custom command instead of my shell." option
5. write "zsh" in "Custom command" textbox

That's it. Next time you start Terminal it opens with zsh.

Comment: This doesn't work for everything, as opening a folder to the terminal will ignore the path parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately it always opens at default location... @LouisGarczynski, do you know how to make it handle the intial location?

Comment: I've tried to set the command as /bin/zsh $1, which doesn't work at all. Looking up for the correct argument name has yielded no results

Comment: Looked more into it, it looks like terminator doesn't pass the path to the shell. Checking with using 'printenv' as the custom command. Looks like it's chsh or nothing.

Comment: Found a working solution, added it as an answer

Comment: @LouisGarczynski after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 it seems to work now for me fine as described in this answer.

Comment: Tested on 18.04 on my end, so maybe there's a blocked update to gnome-terminal ?

Comment: "Open in terminal" stops working after this though. How do fix that?

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer works, if you want to keep some of the other features, such as opening a folder in terminal, or having  the terminal remember the last paths, you can try adding this as the first line to your `.bashrc`:

```bsh
[ -n "$GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN" ] && [ -x "$(command -v zsh)" ] && exec zsh "$@"
```

- `[ -n "$GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN" ]` checks for the GNOME Terminal.
- `[ -x "$(command -v zsh)" ]` checks if zsh exists.
- `exec zsh "$@"` starts zsh with the same argument as bash.

Comment: This has the added benefit that any exports you have in your `.bashrc` will exist in your `zsh` session. It doesn't work for aliases though.

Answer (score 0):

As @MaciekS's answer, in current terminal window, then right-click, select the "Preferences" tab, then in the new open window select "Profile",then select the top bar tab "Command", then you'll get an image like below.

Profile tab:

[image: profile tab]

Finally, in the textbox "Custom Command" area, input "zsh", then open a new terminal, and you will find it has worked.